# Why some properties of dial in tab stored in two attributes?

Tags: active-directory

Verify Caller ID of dial-in tab in user object stored in two attributes(msNPSavedCallingStationID and msNPCallingStationID).But two attributes values are same.why they store same values in two attibutes?what is the use?what is the difference between msNPSavedCallingStationID and msNPCallingStationID?

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests and determined that the value of `msNPSavedCallingStationID` is what is shown by Active Direcotry Users and Computers when viewing properties of the user, `msNPCallingStationID` is the actual value used.

As to why this is the case, I can't say, perhaps `msNPCallingStationID` changes temporarily?